# how to send simply ajax-request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

help please send ajax-request.

html:

```
<p><a id="test">Hello</a></p>
```

js:

```
$(function() {
  $("#test").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/xhr_test/",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType:"html",
        data: {
            "phone": 1,
            "skype": 2,
            "other": 3,
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Ошибка получения запроса');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert('ajax worked' + data);
        }
    }); 
  });
});
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^xhr_test/$', 'views.xhr_test', name='xhr_test'),
```

views.py:

```
def xhr_test(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        message = "Hello AJAX!"
    else:
        message = "Hello"
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

I try to check the data before sending mail using js:

the problem is that after submitting the form I get the message "error mes". at the same time to the browser console output: POST http: // localhost: 8000 / xhr_test / 403 (FORBIDDEN)

please help fix the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send `CSRF` token as well in your request.

From your view pass csrf token to template that will generate your web page, then pass that `csrf` token back with your `ajax` call,so that django recognises you as valid connection.

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
  $("#test").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/xhr_test",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType:"json",
        data: {
            "phone": 1,
            "skype": 2,
            "other": 3,
            "csrfmiddlewaretoken": '{{ csrf_token }}'
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Ошибка получения запроса');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert('ajax worked' + data);
        }
    }); 
  });
});
```

**HTML template**

```
{% csrf_token %}
<p><a id="test">Hello</a></p>
```

**views.py**

```
def xhr_test(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        phone = request.POST['phone']
    data_to_send = {}
    data_to_send.update({'data':phone})
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(data_to_send),content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: thank you. 
but in the case of form I did send: 
csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('#myForm input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
but my question now is no form. so it is unclear what value is contained in the {{ csrf_token }}

Comment: but my question now is no form...<p><a id="test">Hello</a></p>

Comment: I have tested it without form now and it works and added the code to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you need to include the `csrfmiddlewaretoken` in your ajax call.

```
$(function() {
  $("#test").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/xhr_test/",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "html",
        data: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{csrf_token}}",
            phone: 1,
            skype: 2,
            other: 3,
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Ошибка получения запроса');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert('ajax worked' + data);
        }
    }); 
  });
});
```