# csrf token in html, but cookie can not be set

Tags: python, django

First, I go to localhost:8000 to see the following page:

```
</div>        

< form id="SignUpForm"  name="form_signupform"  method="post" action="hello/" > 

{% csrf_token %}  
< fieldset class="roundedCorners"  style = "display: table;"  >
< legend align="center"><em>Sign Up</em></legend>
< p></p>
< p style="display: block;">

etc.
```

At localhost:8000 the above page view is served using the function in views.py:

```
def login(request):  
    c = {}  
    c = {'query': 'abcd.com'}  
    response = render_to_response('index.html', c,context_instance=RequestContext(request))  
    return response
```

Here, in the served page source I can see the csrf value like the following:

```
< form  id="SignUpForm"  name="form_signupform"  method="post" action="hello/" >
< input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken'      
value='rjbU4k8DY3EEBWVhlsgIYU3gEu4x3ctM' / >   
< fieldset class="roundedCorners"  style = "display: table;" >
< legend align="center"><em>Sign Up</em></legend>
< p >< /p >
< p style="display: block;"> 

etc.
```

On pressing submit button another view is called. In `views.py`:

```
def hello(request):  
    if request.method == "POST":  
        return HttpResponseRedirect("genResp1.html")  
    else:  
        return HttpResponseRedirect("genResp2.html")
```

BUT, on pressing submit button i get the following error:

```
Forbidden (403)
    CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
...
...
Help
Reason given for failure:
    CSRF cookie not set.
```

:: i have consulted a) django docs, b) stackoverflow.com, c) google, etc. I have tried every possible permutation-combination of code... but the eror never changed...(I can set cookie calling set_cookie function... that works fine... but csrf cookie can not be set... why?) PLEASE DO NOT SEARCH NET AND WRITE SOLUTION. I HAVE SEARCHED THAT FOR LAST 6 DAYS.I HAVE TRIED ALL FORMS OF VIEW FUNCTION. ONE OF THEM IS GIVEN ABOVE. IF YOU HAVE DONE THAT CSRF JOB BY YOURSELF AND GOT IT RUNNING THEN ONLY PLEASE WRITE HOW YOU DID THAT... (me using python 3.4 and django 1.7)

Comment: Are you sending csrf token also when making a `POST` request ?

Comment: i dont understand your solution... i thinkl its enough to use request contest... can u help me with a few lines of code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897149/how-to-send-simply-ajax-request/25897210#25897210

Comment: well, that u pointed out is using javascript and ajax... but i want to know the soln using html5 and built in django functions... do u know how to send that token back to the redirected form?

Comment: Using the developer tools can you check if the csrf cookie is set in the browser or the cookie is disabled.

Comment: well... u did not notice that i said "...(I can set cookie calling set_cookie function... that works fine... but csrf cookie can not be set... why?) ..."...   :)

Comment: ok... i figured it out the above is correct... but in the settings i wrote the following...                                                       # CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = 'csrfmiddlewaretoken'
# CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'localhost:8000'  # your domain name
# CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
# CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
# CSRF_COOKIE_AGE = None
# CSRF_COOKIE_USED = True
# CSRF_COOKIE_PATH = 'C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\cookFol'
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True                               ... see i commented out those and it worked...

Answer (score 1):

The problem get solved by setting `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE` to `False`, since I was NOT using HTTPS on my development machine:

1. Modified the file `settings.py` which had the following line:

   ```
   CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
   SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
   ```
2. Changed it to:

   ```
   CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
   SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
   ```

Answer (score 0):

ok... i figured it out the above is correct... but in the settings i wrote the following...

```
# CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = 'csrfmiddlewaretoken' 
# CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'localhost:8000' # your domain name 
# CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False 
# CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False 
# CSRF_COOKIE_AGE = None 
# CSRF_COOKIE_USED = True 
# CSRF_COOKIE_PATH = 'C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\cookFol'
```

SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True

... see i commented out those and it worked... 
The above codes are as same, may be there were any mismatch in those settings customization...